# How to set a matrix index to the estimate in R

Tags: r

I want to set the index of a matrix to the given Beta_1 value in R

```
library(MASS)
beta_1_hat <- matrix(0,nrow=100)
for(i in seq(1,100, by=1)) {
  mu=rep(0, 3)
  Sigma=matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,0.5,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,1),nrow=3)
  beta_0=1
  beta_1=2
  beta_2=3
  beta_3=0
  Beta=matrix(c(beta_0,beta_1,beta_2,beta_3),nrow=4)
  n=1000
  X<- mvrnorm(n , mu,Sigma)
  X_extended=cbind(rep(1,n), X)
  sigma=1
  epsilon<-matrix(rnorm(n,sd=sigma^2),nrow=n)
  Y<- X_extended%*%Beta+epsilon
  modbeta <- lm(Y~X[,1])
  beta_1_hat[[i]] <- modbeta$coefficients(X[,1])
}
print(beta_1_hat)
```

I thought `beta_1_hat[[i]] <- modbeta$coefficients(X[,1])` would set the given index to the value, but an error pops up `Error in modbeta$coefficients(X[, 1]) : attempt to apply non-function`.
How would I fix this?

Comment: `modbeta$coefficients` isn't a function, but you are using it like one by following it with an open parenthesis `(`. What are you trying to compute there?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It should be

```
library(MASS)
beta_1_hat <- matrix(0,nrow=100)
for(i in seq(1,100, by=1)) {
  mu=rep(0, 3)
  Sigma=matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,0.5,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,1),nrow=3)
  beta_0=1
  beta_1=2
  beta_2=3
  beta_3=0
  Beta=matrix(c(beta_0,beta_1,beta_2,beta_3),nrow=4)
  n=1000
  X<- mvrnorm(n , mu,Sigma)
  X_extended=cbind(rep(1,n), X)
  sigma=1
  epsilon<-matrix(rnorm(n,sd=sigma^2),nrow=n)
  Y<- X_extended%*%Beta+epsilon
  modbeta <- lm(Y~X[,1])
  beta_1_hat[[i]] <- summary(modbeta)$coefficients[2, 1]
}
```